# Dota2: Cancelled clarity potion after Nyx Spiked Carapace

Tags: dota-2

As the title suggest, I'm wondering how the mechanics of Nyx's ability *Spike Carapace* work with regards to damage block.

I saw a video recently where the Nyx had an active clarity on himself, was then auto attacked by the enemy but used *Spike Carapace* to block the damage from the attack. This still cancelled the clarity.

Is that by design? Is that a bug? Or do I just not have the right understanding of what is blocked or how the attack is blocked with *Spiked Carapace*?

The incident in question happens at 4:47, and the streamer asks the question too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attacks that deal no damage will still interrupt the effect of Clarities, Salves, the healing from Urn of Shadows, and anything else that is cancelled by being attacked by a player. Other examples are an Urn of Shadow charge being dispelled while the hero is under the effect of False Promise, Oracle's ult, which delays all damage until the end of its duration, or being attacked while under the effect of Guardian Angel, which negates all physical damage.

Comment: Gotcha... So the actual mechanism of something being triggered by an auto attack or damage source is what cancels the clarity/salve/urn.  Compared then to Puck's Phase Shift... While not being able test, I would imagine it saves your clarity because phase shift prevents the attack from ever getting to you. Or Blink dodge for that matter

Comment: @dasMetzger That's right, as long as you don't get hit, you won't receive the on hit effects.

Comment: Regarding damage source that is not an autoattack it has to do damage over a certain threshold (20dmg/sec if I'm not mistaking). For example you can heal using salve through bs ult (at least at lvl 1) if you don't have boots, or through pudge rot lvl 1 and 2.